# Flutter, updating variable values not appearing in application

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After defining a variable ("xyz" at screenshot), I fetched some data on my firestore database, then changed that variable value to data i fetched from firestore. When I print the changed variable with "print()"  it appears at "Run" the value I fetched, which is what I want. But when I run the app, the text I assigned as changed variable appears on the screen with old value like I never changed it after defining. [the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwH2w.png)

When I print(xyz); it appears as the data from firestore, so there is no problem at database connection. I just want to update the value appears at screen too.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could also listen to those snapshots without using `StreamBuilder` or any Flutter widget with the `listen()` method like this:

```
final fieldValue = "initial value";
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .doc(documentPath)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
      final data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      fieldValue = data["field"];
      print(fieldValue);
    });
```

the `fieldValue` will be updated now every time an update happens to the document, and it will print it automatically in the console with the `print()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am trying the replace the value of "String x = "Hi unknown" with the fieldValue, so i writed "x = fieldValue". But when i run the project it still appears as "Hi unknown", but after i hot reload the value I want is appearing. So when I hit Hot Reload it works as it should, but at first run it appears like nothing chanced.

Comment: And when I try to use fieldValue instead of "x" I get this error "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'"

Comment: yes, it's because for the first time, it will be null since it has no value until a new snapshot is for from the Stream

Comment: I edited the code again, now the fieldValue has an initial value.

Comment: Now the error is gone, but instead of showing the value fetched, it is appearing on screen as "initial value".

Comment: please, can you host the code you used on gist or dartpad and then give me its link.

Comment: Of course, here: https://gist.github.com/Beratini6910/fbea7c6df7c304e4d20745925102cfcf

Comment: I am trying to replace "xyz" with a field named "Dersiniz" of "Kullanicilar/11@gmail.com'. But when i do that with the code you shared, on screen I am viewing "initial value" instead of fetched value from database. But when i print("fieldValue") i can see the value I wanted to fetch from database. It is just not appearing at screen.

Comment: try this https://gist.github.com/anasfik/fc4c6a5b59e11ccdffd8b3a23fa1f2b2

Comment: I am so grateful. I hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

as I see in the screenshot, you're getting your document's data with a `Future`, and the Future is useful when you need to call data just once :

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(documentPath).get(); // Future

FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(documentPath).get(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text("${snapshot.data!.data()}");
    }
    return Text("something else");
  },
);
```

This will get the snapshot only once, even if you updated the document data, nothing will update on the screen until you make manually a new request to get another snapshot.

well the Firebase SDK for Flutter provide also `Stream` of snapshots for `DocumentSnapshot` and `CollectionSnapshot`, which listen directly to it, so whenever you have an update on your target, that stream will be notified and provide a new snapshot for that new updated data, and you can use it like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(documentPath).snapshots(), // Stream


StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(documentPath).snapshots(), // Stream
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
    final currentData = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
     final fieldValue = currentData["fieldString"];
      return Text("$fieldValue");
    }
    return Text("something else");
  },
);
```

change `fieldString` with your field name to get its value.

Now every update you do to the `DocumentSnapshot`, the `StreamBuilder` will get that new snapshot from the `Stream` and update the UI based on it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. When I try to use second code you suggested I am getting this error "The named parameter 'future' isn't defined.". And even without this error, how can I get value of a field and assign it to a variable? I'm sorry if I'm asking silly questions, I am new at Flutter.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I will edit it

Comment: try now, I edited it to stream property

Comment: Thank you, now the error is gone. How can I get value of a field and assign it to a variable with this snapshot?

Comment: wait I will add it also

Comment: check it again, it gets a specifc field from document

Comment: let me know if there is any problems.

Comment: Thank you. The thing I am trying to find out is assign the value of a field to a variable. For example defining  "String x;" and then assigning value of a field to it, then when I want that data just gonna need to call "x" variable.

Comment: like what I did in the StreamBuilder's fieldValue variable ? or something else ?

Comment: Oh, do you mean storing the snapshot only in a variable without using widgets on flutter ?

Comment: Yes, i just want to assign data to one variable, than use it like normal variables.

Comment: The problem is I cant call fieldValue outside of StreamBuilder. The thing i am trying to do in my project right now is change a string variable's value (which is "String x = "Hi unknow" in my project)with value of a field in firestore.

Comment: wait I will another answer without flutter widget

Comment: check the other answer,